# Best way to administrate a very dynamic network

Tags: networking

This question is related to organizing a network:
We are using a virtual infrastructure (very dynamically) and native installation for our server environment. All devices are connected with cisco switches (2960, 3750, Nexus 5k).

this network is like a testing environment - servers are setup without a lot of processes behind and documentation about these. That's not a traditional server environment.

Due to many people which work there, it could happen that an ip address is used twice. we have used an excel sheet, but during the laziness of some people, the document isn't very proper.

Is there a way or an implemented idea how to generate a list which ip adresses of our network are already used.
I thought about sending arp-tables of the edge-ports from the switches with snmp to a log-server and working there with the information.
please feel free to comment any thoughts about this

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Get rid of network anarchy first.

Comment: you're right.. That would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a quick check you can use the ARP Tables on your Cisco L3 Switches. Go to the Default Gateway Switch(es) and ping the Broadcast IP:

```
ping 255.255.255.255
```

After that use the

```
show arp
```

command. You will receive the current ARP Table for all VLANs. 
You should also find an Error Message in the L3 Switch Logs when they discover a Duplicate IP.

For long term Management you should use a Software using snmp,cpd,arp,... to collect Network Information. I would suggest you NeDi for this

http://www.nedi.ch/

It's a very good Management Software for Cisco Networks. In newer releases there is also a Management for HP, VMWare ESX, Nortel, Juniper, Enterasys,... but i not tested any of this vendors myself yet. I use NeDi in different Cisco Networks and it works very well.